# Deploy NextJs SSR to Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: azure, next.js, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to deploy NextJs SSR to Azure Static Web Apps?

In Microsoft doc they said

> In the Build Details section, select Custom from the Build Presets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs

But I see in Build Presets there is NextJs
[Build Presets Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktx5m.png)

Is it new feature that supports all NextJs functionalities including SSR ?

In Azure/static-web-apps repo I found one comment from 8 March 2022 that says:

> As of today, Static Web Apps only supports static rendering of Next.js Apps. However, the team is currently working on supporting framework-specific Server-side rendering for Next.js and you should be seeing a public preview of the same soon.

https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/749#issuecomment-1061993049

I created Azure Static Web App with NextJs preset with **output_location: ".next"**
because when run **"npm run build"** the output folder is **".next"**

but GitHub hook failed with this error

> Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (.next). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.
> If your application contains purely static content, please verify that the variable 'app_location' in your workflow file points to the root of your application.
> If your application requires build steps, please validate that a default file exists in the build output directory.

The only way I could deploy NextJs in Azure Static Web Apps is when I change the build command in **package.json** to

**"build": "next build && next export"**,

and for output location type **"out"** which is SSG but not SSR.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing. It looks like Static Web Apps doesn’t support SSR yet but they may add support soon as you’ll see here https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/749

BTW, I used the same commands to deploy the static content to Azure SWA.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/discussions/921

This will be supported soon, Microsoft is working on this

Answer (score 0):

SSR is now supported in preview.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/extending-next-js-support-in-azure-static-web-apps/ba-p/3627975